# Gett subquery count with and without filtering

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to return the row count of the subselect (before it's filtered) and the count with the where clause applied.

I can't use a CTE since the first statement of the script must be a SELECT statement. A CTE would need to be declared before everything else.

In this case, it would return the values 5 and 3.

Please ignore the actual query since I created it for the purposes of showing the issue.

```
declare @table table
(
    FName varchar(20),
    EmpId int
)
insert into @table
values
('Joe A', 1),
('Joe M', 1),
('Bob K', 2),
('Bob J', 2),
('Joe Z', 4)

select count(*)
--(SELECT COUNT(fname) FROM (AllEmployees)) AS AllNames -- This generates syntax error
from 
(
    select fname from @table
) as AllEmployees
group by left(fname, 3)
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Why can’t you use CTEs?

Comment: The way these queries are executed, ctes have been giving us trouble.

Comment: Sounds like you're just forgetting a semicolon...

Comment: If you are running SQL Server, there's really no reason (aside from syntax) that CTEs should "give you trouble" ...... if a CTE is part of an ideal solution, then you really shouldn't have to find an alternative workaround

Comment: The first statement must be a SELECT statement. The CTE would need to be declared at the top since there can't be one within a subselect.

Comment: Aside: The subquery `SELECT COUNT(fname) FROM (AllEmployees)` has parentheses around the table name. That probably isn't helping.

Answer (score 2):

Edited after the question was updated:

Regardless of where your data resides (table, CTE, etc.) the general pattern for getting a filtered count will look like this:

```
select count(CASE WHEN columnName like 'value_I_want%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as filteredCount, 
Count(*) as countEverything
from TableName
```

The CASE expression inside the count does the filtering. NULL does not get counted. Once you have that down, you can substitute your data into the mix:

```
declare @table table
(
    FName varchar(20),
    EmpId int
)
insert into @table
select 'Joe A', 1 union
select 'Joe M', 1 union
select 'Bob K', 2 union
select 'Bob J', 2 union
select 'Joe Z', 4

select count(CASE WHEN FName like 'Joe%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as filteredCount, 
    Count(*) as countEverything
    from @table
```

The above returns 3, 5 when I run it in SSMS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited the query a bit so that it looks more like my actual query.

Comment: @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf Updated my answer. Should answer the question.